# update-command-not-found gives « KeyError: 'rpi' » after upgrading to Rapsbian Buster (testing)

Tags: raspbian, apt, raspbian-buster

I just updated my Raspbian to Buster (testing) by editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` and replacing all `stretch` with `buster` and doing `apt update && apt dist-upgrade`. Now `apt update` always shows an error when updating CommandNotFound database, as well as manually running `update-command-not-found` as root. How can I get rid of this error?

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi # update-command-not-found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/update-command-not-found", line 26, in <module>
    col.create(db)
  File "/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 94, in create
    self._fill_commands(con)
  File "/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 132, in _fill_commands
    self._parse_single_contents_file(con, f, fp.stdout)
  File "/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 271, in _parse_single_contents_file
    priority = component_priorities[component]
KeyError: 'rpi'
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi # echo $?
1
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi #
```

Comment: Per https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95292/update-command-not-found-gives-keyerror-rpi-after-upgrading-to-rapsbian-b#comment154951_95293 I needed to also update `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list` to fix the stretch reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dirty Fix:

Add a line of `'rpi': 10,` to the end of list `component_priorities` in `/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py`.

Result should like this:

```
component_priorities = {
    'main': 120,
    'universe': 100,
    'contrib': 80,
    'restricted': 60,
    'non-free': 40,
    'multiverse': 20,
    'rpi': 10,
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at the Python traceback, I located the line that caused the error at line 271 of file `/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py`. I opened that file and replaced the line with

```
priority = component_priorities.get(component)
```

and ran `update-command-not-found` again, and it completed without problems.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have to also update the repository for the Raspbian kernel and drivers in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list`?

Comment: @Ingo I did that as well but the problem still persisted.

Comment: I did `priority = component_priorities.get(component,0)`